# iOS/Swift: Using touchesmoved to move UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

new to Swift/iOS.  I'm trying to move an UIImageView when touchesmoved is called.  But, I can't seem to get it working.  The touchesMoved won't find a subview that matches the touch.view and therefore won't move the subview.

There are UILabels in the view that do work with the touchesMoved function, but the UIImageViews will not.

Any ideas would be really helpful.  Thanks.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first as UITouch!
    let location = touch.locationInView(view)

    let imageView = TouchPointModel(frame: CGRectMake(location.x - frameSize * 0.5, location.y - frameSize * 0.5, frameSize, frameSize), image: UIImage(named: "Feedback_Winner.png")!)

    view.addSubview(imageView)
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch:AnyObject in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInView(view)

        for subview in view.subviews {
            if touch.view == subview {
                print("yahtzee")
                subview.center = location
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the TouchPointModel for reference:

```
class TouchPointModel: UIImageView {
    init(frame:CGRect, image:UIImage) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.image = image
        self.opaque = false
        self.userInteractionEnabled = true

        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse], animations: {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3)
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to add an image view at the point where the touch starts, but the `view` property of a touch never changes. That is, `touch.view` doesn't change as you move your finger around to different views, and for that reason `touch.view` will never correspond to the image view that you're adding in `touchesBegan(withEvent)`.

<sub>PS: It's more than a little confusing to name your class `TouchPointModel`, as "model" and "view" classes are two entirely distinct kinds of objects in the standard model-view-controller paradigm.</sub>

Comment: thanks, that makes sense.  so is there a property of touch that can be used to find the corresponding view a move it?

Comment: `touch.view` is the view where the touch started, and that's usually the one you want to go with if you're using a touch to drag a view around. If you want to move an image view around, you have a couple options. One is to add the image view to the view hierarchy before the touch begins so that `touch.view` *is* the view that you're moving. Another is to keep doing what you're doing, but keep track of the image view that you insert by some other means (ivar or property), and then move that. Either way, you shouldn't need to iterate through all your subviews to find the one to move.